# XPath notebook: XError:Focus for / is absent; code:XPDY0002

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, xpath

I have a simple question for you. I want to count how many nodes contained in the heavy XML file.

For example: (In this case, Xpath expression should give me count of bridge node which is 1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<full_info>
  <bridge>
    <FFF3>12314</FFF3>
    ...
  </bridge>
</full_info>
```

This is my Xpath expression:

```
count(//full_info/bridge)
```

But this command continuously giving that error:

> XError:Focus for / is absent; code:XPDY0002

How to solve this problem? please help me

Comment: Well, how do you run that code against the XML, are you doing that writing e.g. C# or Java code, using some XPath library? Please show us the necessary details. Or are you using some VS Code extension? Then tell us which one you use and how you use it. The error message seems to suggest that the focus/context for XPath evaluation has not been set.

Comment: If that is using the XPath notebook extension make sure you have a saved XML input file open in VS Studio code.

Comment: @MartinHonnen sorry about that I am currently using Xpath notebook

Comment: I can't reproduce that as long as I have a saved XML document open in VS code then the XPath 3.1 notebook extension uses that document as the context item and I don't get the named error. It only appears if no XML document to serve as the context item is opened in VS Code.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sorry about that, my xml file is huge so big. VScode give me out of memory exception. So in this case, notebook actually couldn't execute such commands. I am testing this count command on small xml file, it works!. It means my question changed like how to fully open big file on VScode?

Comment: If you don't open the file in a VS Code tab but in XPath use `count(doc('file.xml')//full_info/bridge)`, does that work without memory problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, traditional XPath is not a good tool to deal with huge (GBs of input) XML documents so you might want to look into more advanced techniques like XSLT 3 with streaming where Saxon 10 EE or SaxonCS allow running

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  
  <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(//full_info/bridge)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and would not build a complete in memory tree but rather stream through and count nodes.

The other option would be to look into BaseX or eXist-db or other XML database systems, there you would need to put that huge XML into a db first but then hopefully the XPath or XQuery to count nodes doesn't cause out of memory problems.